# google map multiple markers open info window by external link

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have integrated the google map with multiple markers. By default 1 marker should be displayed. By clicking marker 2 link marker2 location need to open. By default how to open the info window.

```
  Here is the fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/sathyavs/kjxphszm/2/][1]
```

To open the info window by default I used the following code.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[id],'click');
```

But in the fiddle the markers are not displayed by clicking the corresponding markers link. Its totally frustrating. Please help me. What I am doing wrong.

Comment: A good start would be looking at the browser console and fixing whatever error is coming up there: `Uncaught ReferenceError: showmarker is not defined` and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: Initially u want marker1 to be shown and hide other markers. Later on as he clicks links respective marker should show and open info window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixes in your code and improvements**

1. Removed creating multiple map objects everytime link clicked
2. ShowMarker updated to show marker and panning to that marker when link clicked.

```js
var infowindow = null;    
var arrMarkers = {};
var gmarkers = [];
var map;
// these are location
var sites = [
  ['Miyapur', 17.493336, 78.346531, 4, 'Plot 160, Mytri Nagar,<br> Madinaguda, Miyapur,<br> Hyderabad.<br><br>Phone:<br> 040 65081334, 040 65081335'],
  ['Irving Homestead', 17.402064, 78.484005, 2, 'Saboo R.K. Plaza,<br> Beside HDFC Bank,<br> Himayath Nagar,<br> Hyderabad <br><br>Phone:<br> 040 65355123, 040 65356123'],
  ['Boduppal', 17.419148, 78.584124, 1, 'Plot 160, ColonyBoduppal,<br> Hyderabad.<br><br>Phone:<br> 040 65081334, 040 65081335'],
  ['Habsiguda', 17.363610, 78.554393, 3, '3-73, Street No 6, Habsiguda,<br> Hyderabad. <br><br>Phone:<br> 040 65700233, 040 65700234'],
  ['Banjara Hills', 17.447863, 78.355354, 5, 'Plot 282, Ground Floor,<br> Road 12, Old MLA Colony, Banjara Hills,<br> Hyderabad. <br><br>Phone:<br> 040 65700222, 040 65700333'],
  ['Somajiguda', 17.428951, 78.456014, 6, 'Shop no 23, 6-3-1110, Ground Floor,<br> Amrutha Mall, Somajiguda,<br> Hyderabad. <br><br>Phone:<br> 040 65700233, 040 65700234'],
   ['Kondapur', 17.457073, 78.371499, 7, 'SMR Vinay Technopolis<br> P.NO. 89, Survey<br> No.13, Opposite- S& P Global, Kondapur,<br> Hyderabad. <br><br>Phone:<br> 040 33165120']
];

   
function initMap() {

    var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(17.493336, 78.346531);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: centerMap,
       // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    setMarkers(map, sites,'');
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "loading..."
    });
    //var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
    //bikeLayer.setMap(map);
}

function showmarker(id) { 
    setVisibility(id)
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[id],'click')
    map.panTo(gmarkers[id].getPosition())
}

function setMarkers(map, markers,id) {  
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var sites = markers[i];
    var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: siteLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: sites[0],
        zIndex: sites[3],
        html: sites[4]
    });
    var contentString = "Some content";
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
      console.log('info open');
        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        console.log('info end');
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);           
  }
  setVisibility(0);
}

function setVisibility(id){
  // initial show first marker and hide all   
  for(var i=0;i<gmarkers.length;i++){
    gmarkers[i].setVisible(false); 
  }
  gmarkers[id].setVisible(true); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC85LOYsngItz49WJYalPzgSCGzXS-rU8E&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
    
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<li> <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="showmarker('0')">Marker 1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="showmarker('1')">Marker 2</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="showmarker('2')">Marker 3</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="showmarker('2')">Marker 4</a></li>
```

Comment: how to open the info window by clicking Marker links. On click the marker icon the info window is opened. But it didn't displayed by clicking the links

Comment: Super its working now. But the info window is not opened for the first time. (By default the 1st marker is displayed. At that time the info window is not opened. If I click the marker 1 link it is opened. Do you know Why?

Comment: @SamHanson that's easy. Just call showmarker(0) at end of setMarkers function. That's it.